# Nginix proxy caching - how to check if it is working?

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers

I have set up my nginx.conf file to use proxy caching from tutorials I have found online. However, I am trying to figure out how to check if it is actually working. I've read somewhere that adding add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status; to the config file in the server section should add a caching header to a response that will show if it was from cache (has values of either a HIT, MISS or EXPIRED). However, I'm wondering WHERE I can actually view this header(and its value) as well as if this is the right way/if there is another way. I'm very new to web in general so sorry if this is a noob question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it the right way, to see the headers send back you need to check in your http client. Obviously how to do it, if you can do it, will depend on your client

Here some easy ways to see the headers:

```
1. curl --head http://your-adress
2. wget --server-response http://your-adress
3. in firefox, install the [liveheaders][1] addon,
   go the <url>, rightclick->View page info->headers
4. in opera open dragonfly with ctrl+i
   go to network->make request part of the tool,
   enter http://your-adress, 
   the result with headers will be shown in the response field
```

Comment: Got it! I used curl and I can see the headers now. Thank you very much! :)